# Why did my XML fail to add multiple tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xsd

I created XML in my Ruby on Rails code, and  validated it using an XSD with UTF-16 encoding.

In the XML, when I insert a single name it works, but for  multiple names it raises an error:

```
<city>
    <groups>
      <name></name> 
    </groups>...........It's working fine
</city>

<city>    
    <groups>
      <name></name> 
      <name></name>
    </groups>...........It's raise error
<city>

"FAILED: Error: Element 'name': This element is not expected. at :107."
```

Are  there any restrictions for inserting multiple tags in XML?

Here is my XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>                              
              <xsd:element name="city">                                           
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="groups">
                      <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                          <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                         </xsd:sequence>
                      </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                  </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
```

Here is model:

```
 xml.tag!("city"){
              grp = map_groups(city.groups)
              grp.each { |grp_code|
               xml.groups{
                    xml.name("john")
               }
              } unless grp.empty?
             }
```

Comment: Can you post the code and the full error details? Is it failing when you try to validate with the XSD or at some other point? It looks like the XSD might not allow multiple `<name>` elements under a `<group>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSD doesn't allow multiple names.

Try change 
    `<xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />`
to
    `<xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>`

Comment: Thanks @xing, but i don't have rights to change my XSD. Is there any way to generate XML with existing XSD?

Comment: I'm afraid not, unless you can bypass XSD validation.